# Find a way to filter out swear words even if the user has escaped them

Tags: code-golf

For this, imagine that the following words are really nasty cuss words:

```
Frag, Smeg, Felgercarb, Blatherskite, Dadgum, Fnord, Smurf, Schmit
```

Now, I need to filter out swear words on my website.
Normally the site will search for these words and **** them out:

```
I hate this s****ing cussword filter! It won't let me f***ging swear!
```

But people will just do this

```
I hate this sm.urfing  cussword filter! Good thing I can get around the fr.agging thing.
```

or

```
Holy schm1t, this web application is great!
```

Some more examples that I've seen are on this page:
[Inversoft Profanity Filter](http://www.inversoft.com/features/profanity-filter/)

And then there's this: [Sc***horpe Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sc%2a%2a%2ahorpe_problem)

Challenge: Find the shortest solution, using regular expressions, that removes the most cuss words.

**Note: This is a very very relevant link: [PHP chat log](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14381995#14381995)**

Comment: It would probably be helpful to include a complete list of test cases.

Comment: You don't say how you want the Scunthorpe problem handled. Ignore it, and return Sc***horpe? Or if we should return Scunthorpe, what penalties are there for those who censor it?

Comment: `s/.*//` is the ultimate swearword filter. But yeah, like others have pointed out, this isn't at all a good task in its current shape: it's not very clear what the goal is and how it is scored.

Comment: ...first question on Code Golf...I read the rules but yeah, I didn't phrase the question very well. I'm just really used to StackOverflow.

How can I make the question better?

Comment: @AustinBurk Just a friendly advice, post your question in the sandbox in COde Golf Meta, we will tell you how you can write your question to make it enjoyable for everyone. Edit: although I did the exact same thing when I arrived here.

Comment: This should either be a code golf or popularity contest.  Otherwise, you could maybe have the winner be the code that finds and removes the most cuss words.

Comment: I was going to do 'code golf' but there were only eight questions that used that tag so I decided not to.
I'll edit the question later. Thank you all. I need to go shovel snow though, we just got dumped on.

Comment: Code golf is actually very popular.  Most of the questions have [tag:code-golf] tags.

Comment: The shortest solution that removes the most swearwords is the one FireFly posted in a comment. I think that to save this question you need to write a spec that is sufficiently detailed that every possible test case has one correct output. Effectively, turn it into a regex-golf problem.

Comment: I just realized that that's a sed command there and that it matches everything and removes it, haha